Azure Function Multioutput define parameter
I am using Azure Function v4 with .NET 8.0 as Isolated Process and want to use multiple output binding as described here.
It looks like this:
public class MultiOutputType
{
    [KafkaOutput("BrokerList",
                 "topic")]
    public string KafkaEvent { get; set; }

    public IActionResult HttpResponse { get; set; }
}

and use this class like this
[Function("test")]
public MultiOutputType Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var kafkaEvent = "some event string";
    var httpResponse = new OkObjectResult("Test successful.");

    return new MultiOutputType
    {
        KafkaEvent = kafkaEvent,
        HttpResponse = httpResponse
    };
}

Now I do not want to hardcode parameters like BrokerList or topic defined in KafkaOutput but want to load these values from configuration like local.settings.json or environment variable.
How can I set these values in the attribute from configuration?

I figured it out, it can be done by putting %% around the variables, e.g. %BrokerList% and %topic% and define these values in local.settings.json or environment variable.
Hint: When adding these values in local.settings.json, they have to be put unter node "Values". Defining them by their own will not work (at least for me).
